# Who discovered DNase?

Tags: genetics, biochemistry, proteins

I was recently studying genetics in which  DNase had a crucial role in proving DNA to be the genetic material and I tried to find who discovered DNase (like the discoverer of DNA) but in vain.

Who found the DNA-digesting DNase ?

Comment: You imply (if I’m not mistaken) that you know who discovered DNA. I wonder whether you might be confusing who discovered DNA, who showed it was the genetic material, and who elucidated its structure. If you’re interested in the history of science it might be useful to clarify that while we are about it.

Comment: @David Thanks It clarifies my doubt If you don't mind I have a question that is , In Martha Chase Experiment, It has been proposed that Since Radioactive Nitrogen is Transferred The DNA act as a genetic material but Why can't the transferred material be RNA as It also has same amount Of Nitrogen as of DNA ?

Comment: A principle of this site is that questions should be asked as separate questions, not as add-ons in comments. There are [a few questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=Hershey-Chase) on the Hershey-Chase experiment on this site, and also a [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hershey–Chase_experiment). However the short answer is that the bacteriophages studied consisted of DNA and protein, and the experiment was to distinguish between the two. You need to look at old experiments in their historical context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are, of course, many different deoxyribonucleases (DNase), but the question has other implicit problems. It assumes that there was a single event that resulted in the realization of the existence of a new enzymatic activity. As the Introduction to this [paper by M. McCarty on the purification of one such enzyme in the *Journal of General Physiology* in 1946](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2142737/pdf/123.pdf), science wasn’t (and still often isn’t) quite like that:

> The enzyme which breaks down highly polymerized desoxyribonucleic (sic) acid
> has been known for many years under various names. In 1903, Araki (3)
> reported that crude preparations of trypsin and erepsin brought about
> liquefaction of gels of a thymonucleate prepared according to the
> method of Neumann (4) Although Araki interpreted the effect as being
> proteolytic in nature, his experiments represent the first observations
> on the enzymatic breakdown of this type of nucleic acid. Two years
> later Sachs (5) demonstrated that liquefaction of the nucleate gel by
> pancreatic extracts is caused by an enzyme distinct from trypsin, and
> further presented evidence indicating that trypsin rapidly inactivates
> the nuclease. De la Blanchardière (6) confirmed the findings of Sachs,
> and made several unsuccessful attempts to separate the nuclease from
> the inactivating tryptic enzymes. This writer also devised a more
> quantitative method of measuring the nuclease activity by following the
> fall in viscosity of a dilute solution of thymonucleate during
> digestion with the enzyme.
>
> 3. Araki, T., *Z. physiol. Chem*.,1903,38, 84.
> 4. Sachs, F., *Z. physiol. Chem*.,1905,46, 337.
> 5. De la Blanchardière, P., *Z. physiol. Chem.*, 1913, 87, 291

[*desoxyribonucleic acid* and *thymonucleate* are older terms for DNA and its ionized form]

Many scientists have subsequent been involved in identifying different types of DNase and their roles in DNA metabolism, and anyone wishing to know about a particular DNase would need to research the literature.